# Adding application to "Open With" context menu - QNapi problem

Tags: macos, applications, finder

I have tried many available solutions (searched through similar questions), most of them was quite obvious - like editing `Info.plist` in the application package, but oryginal application Info.plist data seems to look fine (it has correct file type definitions):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>rm</string>
                <string>mpg</string>
                <string>mpeg</string>
                <string>mov</string>
                <string>avi</string>
                <string>rmvb</string>
                <string>mkv</string>
                <string>m4v</string>
                <string>mp4</string>
                <string>asf</string>
                <string>divx</string>
                <string>ogm</string>
                <string>wmv</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>qnapi.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>LSUIElement</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>QNapi</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Created by Qt/QMake</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>qnapi.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>ttxt</string>
    <key>LSUIElement</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Whatever I do, I can't force OS X to show this application in "Open With" context menu after right clicking on a supported file.

I have also tried to reset settings with:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`

but it didn't work.

Updating, removing and reinstalling etc didn't help either. Above is original application plist that works well on other Mac. It seems like only on my OS X it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea what else could I do to make this application available in the "Open With" context menu (the problem is QNapi related only)?

Comment: For what file types?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as any of suggested solutions didn't worked (as I have written).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Can you please this more obvious in the title and the start of the question so we can reopen it?

Comment: I already changed the title and the text and there's already correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got QNapi to show up in the open with menu by changing

```
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>None</string>
```

to

```
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Viewer</string>
```

and then running `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -f /Applications/QNapi.app` and quitting and reopening Finder.

(`lsregister -f` forces a file to be registered even if its modification date has not changed.)